# Formatter error: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter after Windows updates

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF request that was working fine until some windows updates. After that I get this error and I am not able to find out how to solve it.

The error is:There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:CommandRequestResult.  Please see InnerException for more details.

InnerException: Type 'NEntities.IPAElement, NEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not allowed here. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132227 for more information.

Here my class IPAElement and the enum contained inside. Even I change the enum with a string I still get the same error, so it should not be the problem

```
[Serializable()]

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]

public class IPAElement//:ISerializable

{

    public IPAElement(List<string> bodyElNames, List<ElementType> bodyElTypes)

    {

        BodyElement = bodyElNames;

        BodyRowElementType = bodyElTypes;

    }



    public IPAElement()

    { }



    [DataMember]

    public List<string> HeaderElement;



    [DataMember]

    public List<string> BodyElement;



    [DataMember]

    public List<string> FooterElement;



    [DataMember]

    public List<ElementType> HeaderRowElementType;



    [DataMember]

    public List<ElementType> BodyRowElementType;

   

    [DataMember]

    public List<ElementType> FooterRowElementType;

}
```

[Serializable]

public enum ElementType

```
{

    [XmlEnum("1")]

    ElementName = 1,

    [XmlEnum("2")]

    Material = 2,

    [XmlEnum("3")]

    MaterialColor = 3,

    [XmlEnum("4")]

    Notes_1 = 4,

    [XmlEnum("5")]

    Notes_2 = 5,

    [XmlEnum("6")]

    Notes_3 = 6,

};
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?
Thank you
Andrea

Comment: App.config can be used to extend the allowed types list. I think you can try to add NEntities.IPAElement to the list of allowed types.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by a security fix in Windows Update KB4565633.

You'll likely need this, after checking that your use case was not affected by the security vulnerability:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("System.Data.DataSetDefaultAllowedTypes", typeof(IPAElement));
```

On the face of it, it doesn't look like that your `IPAElement` could cause execution of arbitrary code on deserialization, no matter what an evil man in the middle (or evil source) includes in the serialized content, so this kind of a fix should be safe enough in your particular use case.  (I wouldn't be able to say this much if you hadn't provided `ElementType` for review; and I'm still only guessing that `DataMemberAttribute` is what it normally is.)

However, you should not trust my word and you should read up on the vulnerability and reach your own conclusions if your app is supposed to care about security, before you decide to unlock the door which Microsoft chose to lock.